# ¿Cómo puedo setear las propiedades de una clase desde una cadena que posee formato XML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Consulto un WebService y me devuelve una cadena con formato XML y nesecito establecer los valores correspondientes en los atributos de una clase.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Cadena Xml:

```
   <XML_OUTPUT>
         <CONSULTA_PRESTAMO>
          <PRESTAMO>
           <CLIENTE_NUMERO>0001000082</CLIENTE_NUMERO>
           <SUCURSAL>382</SUCURSAL>
           <PRESTAMO_NUMERO>5000000127</PRESTAMO_NUMERO>
           <PRODUCTO_EXTERNO>PRCO_938</PRODUCTO_EXTERNO>
           <FECHA_ALTA>20160401</FECHA_ALTA>
           <FECHA_VTO>20170401</FECHA_VTO>
           <FECHA_DESEMBOLSO>20160401</FECHA_DESEMBOLSO>
           <CAPITAL_ORIGINAL>26000.00</CAPITAL_ORIGINAL>
           <METODO>F</METODO>
           <PLAZO>012</PLAZO>
           <TASA_TIPO>F</TASA_TIPO>
           <TASA>18.0000000000</TASA>
           <DEBITO>382-0123456999</DEBITO>
           <CREDITO>ZZ-3-382-0123456999</CREDITO>
           <MONTO_ULTIMA_CUOTA>2737.42</MONTO_ULTIMA_CUOTA>
           <MONTO_ADEUDADO>26000.00</MONTO_ADEUDADO>
           <FECHA_ULTIMO_PAGO>00000000</FECHA_ULTIMO_PAGO>
           <MONEDA>ARS</MONEDA>
           <VIA_PAGO>3</VIA_PAGO>
           <SITUACION_PRESTAMO>1</SITUACION_PRESTAMO>
           <OBJETO_CONTRATO>GA</OBJETO_CONTRATO>
           <MEDIO>PI</MEDIO>
           <ULTIMA_CUOTA>000</ULTIMA_CUOTA>
           <ULTIMA_CUOTA_ESTADO>00</ULTIMA_CUOTA_ESTADO>
           <GARANTIA>
            <ID_GARANTIA>GARA_501</ID_GARANTIA>
            <DESCRIPCION_GARANTIA>AVAL /SGR INCRP CANC<30 DIAS</DESCRIPCION_GARANTIA>
           </GARANTIA>
           <IMPUESTOS>
            <IMPUESTO>
             <IMP_ID>952500</IMP_ID>
             <IMP_DESC>2- Comisión desembol</IMP_DESC>
             <IMP_MONTO>260.00</IMP_MONTO>
            </IMPUESTO>
            <IMPUESTO>
             <IMP_ID>952801</IMP_ID>
             <IMP_DESC>4- IVA Desembolso</IMP_DESC>
             <IMP_MONTO>54.60</IMP_MONTO>
            </IMPUESTO>
            <IMPUESTO>
             <IMP_ID>952804</IMP_ID>
             <IMP_DESC>4- IVA Desembolso Se</IMP_DESC>
             <IMP_MONTO>67.41</IMP_MONTO>
            </IMPUESTO>
            <IMPUESTO>
             <IMP_ID>952820</IMP_ID>
             <IMP_DESC>4- Impuesto Sello Mu</IMP_DESC>
             <IMP_MONTO>312.00</IMP_MONTO>
            </IMPUESTO>
            <IMPUESTO>
             <IMP_ID>952825</IMP_ID>
             <IMP_DESC>4- Imp.al Sello Soli</IMP_DESC>
             <IMP_MONTO>9.00</IMP_MONTO>
            </IMPUESTO>
            <IMPUESTO>
             <IMP_ID></IMP_ID>
             <IMP_DESC>GASTOS_IMP_DESEMBOLS</IMP_DESC>
             <IMP_MONTO>703.01</IMP_MONTO>
            </IMPUESTO>
           </IMPUESTOS>
           <ERROR></ERROR>
          </PRESTAMO>
         </CONSULTA_PRESTAMO>
</XML_OUTPUT>
```

Clase:

```
public class PrestamoImputado
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "XML_OUTPUT")]
        public class XML_OUTPUT
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CONSULTA_PRESTAMO")]
            public CONSULTA_PRESTAMO CONSULTA_PRESTAMO { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CONSULTA_PRESTAMO")]
        public class CONSULTA_PRESTAMO
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PRESTAMO")]
            public PRESTAMO PRESTAMO { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PRESTAMO")]
        public class PRESTAMO
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CLIENTE_NUMERO")]
            public string CLIENTE_NUMERO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "SUCURSAL")]
            public string SUCURSAL { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PRESTAMO_NUMERO")]
            public string PRESTAMO_NUMERO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PRODUCTO_EXTERNO")]
            public string PRODUCTO_EXTERNO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "FECHA_ALTA")]
            public string FECHA_ALTA { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "FECHA_VTO")]
            public string FECHA_VTO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "FECHA_DESEMBOLSO")]
            public string FECHA_DESEMBOLSO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CAPITAL_ORIGINAL")]
            public string CAPITAL_ORIGINAL { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "METODO")]
            public string METODO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "PLAZO")]
            public string PLAZO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "TASA_TIPO")]
            public string TASA_TIPO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "TASA")]
            public string TASA { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DEBITO")]
            public string DEBITO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "CREDITO")]
            public string CREDITO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "MONTO_ULTIMA_CUOTA")]
            public string MONTO_ULTIMA_CUOTA { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "MONTO_ADEUDADO")]
            public string MONTO_ADEUDADO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "FECHA_ULTIMO_PAGO")]
            public string FECHA_ULTIMO_PAGO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "MONEDA")]
            public string MONEDA { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "VIA_PAGO")]
            public string VIA_PAGO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "SITUACION_PRESTAMO")]
            public string SITUACION_PRESTAMO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "OBJETO_CONTRATO")]
            public string OBJETO_CONTRATO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "MEDIO")]
            public string MEDIO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ULTIMA_CUOTA")]
            public string ULTIMA_CUOTA { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ULTIMA_CUOTA_ESTADO")]
            public string ULTIMA_CUOTA_ESTADO { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "GARANTIA")]
            public GARANTIA GARANTIA { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "IMPUESTOS")]
            public string IMPUESTOS { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ERROR")]
            public string ERROR { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "GARANTIA")]
        public class GARANTIA
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID_GARANTIA")]
            public string ID_GARANTIA { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESCRIPCION_GARANTIA")]
            public string DESCRIPCION_GARANTIA { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: porque defines todo dentro de la clase PrestamoImputado ? eso no es necesario, si quieres tener todos junto podrias poner las diferentes class dentro del mismo namespace en un solo .cs, pero solo estarian en un archivo

Comment: Ok si es valido tu comentario Leandro Tuttini ...Pero como Seteo los atributos con los valores desde la cadena ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes el xml y la estructura de clases que mapea con este solo queda deserializar

[Cómo deserializar un objeto mediante XmlSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object)

algo como ser

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML_OUTPUT));

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(sourceXML))
{
  var putput = (XML_OUTPUT)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```